# Outlook Add-in in read mode automatically opened on activation rule match?

Tags: office-js, outlook-web-addins

We are developing an Outlook Web Add in. The [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook/add-ins/read-scenario) suggests that it is possible to automatically 'open' an add-in when an activation rule is met (e.g regex pattern). However, I can nowhere find a working example of that, neither good documentation.

Does anyone know whether this is really possible? Or is a manual click of a user on the small icon always necessary? Does someone have a good example of a read-mode add-in?

Answer (score 1):

These are call [Contextual Outlook add-ins](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook/add-ins/contextual-outlook-add-ins). You trigger these off the contents of a message using a regular expression.

I suspect however that you misunderstand how this works. They cannot automatically open your add-in within the task pane. Instead, when the pattern is matched it underscores the text it matched (similar to how spelling errors are underscored). Clicking on the underscored text opens your add-in within the message itself.

Answer (score 1):

In the documentation, the term **activation** refers to whether the button or link to launch the add-in is visible. With the exception of [pinnable task pane](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook/add-ins/pinnable-taskpane) add-ins, which are not contextual, the add-in won't launch automatically.

Beyond pinnable task pane add-ins, a click is needed to launch the add-in, either on the add-in's button, in the case of [add-in commands](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook/add-ins/add-in-commands-for-outlook), or on the highlighted text in the message body, in the case of [contextual add-ins](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook/add-ins/contextual-outlook-add-ins).